# How to debug custom font in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, storyboard

I'm having an app with custom font before, so most of the label/button,... all have that custom font, but now the design changed and no longer need that font, so I changed all the font back to some normal already available font, and remove the custom one (files and in plist).

But after that my app keep on crashing at start with `(llib)`, maybe because of leftover but i cant find it anywhere, any tips on finding this leftover font in storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you suspect is the storyboard, open the storyboard as XML source and search for the font, eg:

```
<fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="italicSystem" pointSize="17"/>
```

Comment: yep this is what i did :d

Comment: In my case i got the name of the font then i search it on storyboard xml code then yeah, but i got this from long ago already, thanks anyway :d

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the app and build the project again.  BTW,showing some log will be helpful to find the solution

Comment: I did remove the app and clean and reinstall, no work. And it totally totally no log happened, only 1 line `(llib)` and it set a random breakpoint and stop there, nothing else

Comment: @Tj3n Oh,that is strange! And how about  adding Exception Breakpoint in Xcode?

Comment: I already added, thats why i suspect the error is somewhere in storyboard, but cant find the one view that have custom font, i have about 15 different storyboard files and many view...